# Magento 2 exlude SKUs from discount

Tags: discount, sku, magento2.1.0

I desperately try to generate a discount code that can be applied to all products but one, as this one has a special price already. Looked a several suggestions, but I cannot find the condition/action that let´s me select a certain SKU. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First of all, you need to edit your SKU attribute and set "Use for promotion cart rules" to Yes.

2) After that in your shopping cart price rule add condition SKU is not one of

[image]